# How can i change the webform module background while using rearrange fields module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

How can i change the webform module background while using rearrange fields module in drupal 7

(i.e) i had used black color background in my style sheet. but i need to set the white color background while using those two modules(webform module, rearrange  module). Why i saying these modules in this time is i got the problem after using these modules.

in this module y i am using rearrange module means it is used for me to set the textbox field and selection box field  wherever i wished to place it.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS specify your background: #FFF as !important, that should override any css conflicts from the modules.

```
#webform-id { background: #FFF !important; }
```

Comment: thank your sir for your valuable answer shared to me. And moreover i have another one doubt where will i insert this line. Bcoz my doubt is i want to insert this line into my own created css file or module's css file.

Comment: thank u so much Patrick, i got it. your statement is working well. i works like a charm......